# How to use Binding to change the value of a Bool from another view, while keeping the inits intact?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When a user presses a button I defined in another view. I want to update the ShowingRequest variable to false. But I am unable to do this because when I use @Binding, I get errors in the init

Someone suggested I remove both inits but I am unable to do that because I have other views using that.

this is the View that wants to use the modified value:

```
struct RequestRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: AppStateModel
    @State var showingRequest = false // this is the variable
    
    let type: MessageType
    let text: String
    let newMessageId: String
    
    var isSender: Bool {
        return type == .sent
    }
    
    init(text: String, type: MessageType, newMessageId: String, showingRequest: Bool) {
        self.text = text
        self.type = type
        self.newMessageId = newMessageId
        self.showingRequest = showingRequest
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                if isSender { Spacer() }
                if !isSender {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(model.currentUsername == "joe" ? "photo1" : "photo2")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                }
                VStack{
                    HStack {
                        Text("This user want's to send you this request\n\n\(text)\n\nDo you wanna accept this request?")
                            .foregroundColor(isSender ? Color.white : Color(.white))
                            .padding()
                    }
                    if !isSender && ShowingRequest {
                        Button(requestId: newMessageId, ShowingRequest: false)
                    }
                }
                    .background(isSender ? Color.blue : Color(.black))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(isSender ? .leading : .trailing, isSender ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width/6)
                if !isSender { Spacer() }

            }
            .onAppear{
                model.getShowAcceptValue(requestId: newMessageId) { showAccept in
                    print("ShowAccept value: \(showAccept)")
                    showingRequest = showAccept
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the Button View that updates the value:

```
struct Button: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: AppStateModel
    @State var showingRequest : Bool
    var requestId: String
    init(requestId: String, showingRequest: Bool) {
        self.requestId = requestId
        self.showingRequest = showingRequest
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button(action: {
                self.updateShowAcceptToFalse()
                showingRequest.toggle() // this is the code that updates the value
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.green
                    Text("Accept")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60) // set the height of the button
            
            Button(action: {
                self.updateShowAcceptToFalse()
                showingRequest.toggle() // this is also the code that updates the value
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                    Text("Deny")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60) // set the height of the button
        }
        .frame(height: 60) // set the height of the HStack container
    }
    private func updateShowAcceptToFalse() {
        model.updateShowAcceptToFalse(requestId: requestId)
    }
}
```

When I tried setting the variables to Binding I got errors like:

- 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
- Return from    initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: Please name variables and properties with starting lowercase letter. And you cannot initialize `@State` property wrappers just with assigning the value in `init`. Delete both `init` methods and replace `@State` with `@Binding` in `Button`

Comment: I can’t delete the initializers because I have other views that depend on them

Comment: You can, they are for free (the compliler creates them on your behalf).

Comment: Oh really? thank you so much for the help, my program works now as expected.